# Get data from sqlite database using LIKE cmd %pattern% works but '%'+pattern+'%' didnt work

Tags: sql, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to search and filter the sqlite database based on a input provided by user using SQL like command. %pattern% works fine, but %+pattern+% format didnt work, Anyother way of using the same?

I have tried the different forms of the query in DB browser for sqlite.. Didnt find luck..

Code:
return this.database.executeSql(`"SELECT * FROM table where name LIKE '%'+im+'%'",[] )`

Expected to see the same output as %im% when using '%'+im+'%'  and "im" will be replaced by user's input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `||` concatenate strings:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%' || im || '%'
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d6fc773c3db5727c7bef4b96da797aba)**